# How to find similar column of two n*m array?

Tags: python, list

```
array1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 5, 8], [5, 6, 9] ]
array2 = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 8]]
```

array2 has a similar column in array1 at index 0 and 2
I want index as output that is 0 and 2

Is it possible to solve without using any long for loop in python?

Comment: By "similar" do you mean "identical"? Also -- are you thinking of the inner lists as being *columns* rather than *rows*?

Comment: I mean exactly the same as shown in the example.

Comment: yes, I am considering the inner list as a column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy` and use `all` and `any` like below:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array1 = np.array(array1) 
>>> array2 = np.array(array2)

>>> res = (array1 == array2[:,None]).all(-1).any(0)

>>> res
array([ True, False,  True, False])

>>> idx, = np.nonzero(res)
>>> idx
array([0, 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done without some sort of open or hidden iteration. Some approach with a set and a comprehension:

```
s2 = set(map(tuple, array2))
indices = [i for i, t in enumerate(map(tuple, array1)) if t in s2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a list comprehension.

```
array1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 5, 8], [5, 6, 9] ]
array2 = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 8]]

output = [i for i in range(len(array1)) if array1[i] in array2]
#[0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary. This avoids quadratic behavior:

```
array1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 5, 8], [5, 6, 9] ]
array2 = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 8]]

d = {tuple(column):i for i,column in enumerate(array1)}
duplicates = [d[tuple(column)] for column in array2 if tuple(column) in d]
print(duplicates) #[0,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use:

```
array1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 5, 8], [5, 6, 9] ]
array2 = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 8]]

res = [array1.index(elem) for elem in array1 if elem in array2]
# [0, 2]
```

what is equivalent of:

```
res = []
for elem in array1:
    if elem in array2:
        res.append(array1.index(elem))
print (res)
# [0, 2]
```